# Copy xml parent element and attribute content to child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, element

Couldn't get the posted answer to work - the example below is more real so may help explain better what I am trying to do:

The data currently looks like this:

```
<LabTest_ID>0001</LabTest_ID>

<FullName>Cluster of differentiation 19+, lambda+ count</FullName>

<SnomedCT conceptId="799711000000109" preferredTerm="Count of cells positive for both CD19 and lambda" />

<CollectedSpecimen id="blood" type="Blood" snomedCTConceptId="119297000">
    <CollectionMethod id="L0000" name="Arterial" snomedCTConceptId="122552005" />
    <CollectionMethod id="L0050" name="Venous" snomedCTConceptId="122555007" />
</CollectedSpecimen>

<CollectedSpecimen id="bonemarrow" type="Bone marrow" snomedCTConceptId="119359002">
    <CollectionMethod id="L0001" name="Aspiration" snomedCTConceptId="801861000000103" />
</CollectedSpecimen>
```

I would like to transform the output for CollectionMethod from this:

```
<CollectionMethod id="L0000" name="Arterial" snomedCTConceptId="122552005" />
```

to this:

```
<CollectionMethod LabTest_ID = "0001" type = "Blood" id="L0000" name="Arterial" snomedCTConceptId="122552005" />
```

That is to say I want to add LabTest's 'LabTest_ID' and CollectedSpecimen's 'type' as additional attributes to CollectedMethod.

I am very new to XML and have tried the following code which almost works, but it outputs LabTest_ID only in the first occurrence of CollectionMethod for each CollectedSpecimen rather than in each one.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dataroot>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </dataroot>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CollectionMethod/@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CollectedSpecimen/@type" />
        <xsl:template match="CollectedSpecimen[@type]/*[1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                    <CollectedSpecimen-type>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../@type" />
                    </CollectedSpecimen-type>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="CollectionMethod">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CollectionMethod">
        <CollectionMethod>
            <LabTest_ID><xsl:value-of select="../../LabTest_ID"/></LabTest_ID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </CollectionMethod>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you doing this in Excel or parsing with something like Python?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to import data from an xml file into MS Access but it doesn't keep the relationships. I was hoping to add the ids of the Grandparent and Parent into the Grandchild so that I can maintain those relationships when I import the data into Access.

Answer (score 2):

The following template adds the new attributes to your XML. The *identity template* copies all nodes except the `Grandchild` elements which are handled by the more specific template.

```
<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="Grandchild">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />              <!-- copies all existing attributes -->
        <xsl:attribute name="Childid">           <!-- Adds the additional Childid attribute -->
          <xsl:value-of  select="../@id" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Parentid">          <!-- Adds the additional Parrentid attribute -->
          <xsl:value-of  select="../../Parent_ID" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```